# lisp function to concatenate a list of strings

Tags: common-lisp, string-concatenation

I need to write a function that will concatenate a list into a string. example:
    (concatString (quote ("hello" " world"))) ==> "hello world"

here is what i have so far:

```
(defun concatString (list)
  "A non-recursive function that concatenates a list of strings."
  (cond
   ((not (listp list))
     (princ "Error: argument to concatNR must be a list")(terpri) ())) ; check if parameter is a list

  (if (not (null list)) ;check if list is not null
      (let ((result (car list)))
        (dolist (item (cdr list))
          (if (stringp item)
              (setq result (concatenate result item)))          
        )
      )
  )
)
```

I'm getting a "Error: "hello" is and illegal type specifier" message when i try to run it.  I've tried a bunch of ways to modify this function and i havent been able to figure it out. does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`concatenate` requires a *sequence type specifier* as its second argument. To concatenate two strings, you should call `concatenate` as:

```
(concatenate 'string "hello" "world")
```

Another bug in your code: you do not make sure that the `car` of the list is a string before assigning it to `result`. By fixing your code, I came up with the following implementation:

```
(defun concatString (list)
  "A non-recursive function that concatenates a list of strings."
  (if (listp list)
      (let ((result ""))
        (dolist (item list)
          (if (stringp item)
              (setq result (concatenate 'string result item))))
        result)))

;; tests
> (concatString (list "hello" " world"))
"hello world"
> (concatString (list "hello" 1 2 3 " world"))
"hello world"
> (concatString (list "hello" 1 2 "3" " world"))
"hello3 world"
> (concatString (list 1 2 3 "hello" " world"))
"hello world"
```

The following redefinition of `concatString` is more efficient as it does not create many intermediary string objects:

```
(defun concatString (list)
  "A non-recursive function that concatenates a list of strings."
  (if (listp list)
      (with-output-to-string (s)
         (dolist (item list)
           (if (stringp item)
             (format s "~a" item))))))
```

Comment: Im checking if its a string because for the assignment, if its a number it shouldn't be added to the string.  Thank you very much though the fix worked!!! =)

Comment: That's relatively bad: you are concatenating repeatedly creating new result strings all the time. This possibly creates a large amount of garbage.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16):

Just use the format function on a list, this will convert everything to strings and concatenate them with the correct format string.

```
(defun my-concat( list )
  (format nil "~{~a~}" list))
```

If you want to concatenate them with a space use this form with the "~^" directive:

```
(defun my-concat( list )
  (format nil "~{~a~^ ~}" list))
```

If you'd like to filter out the results, you can just transform the list before formatting it.

```
(defun my-concat(list)
  (format nil "~{~a~^ ~}" (remove-if-not #'stringp list)))
```

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned that if that it should ignore items in the list that are not strings.  so if an item is an number it should not add it to the string.

Comment: Yeah, that changes the scope of the problem quite a bit

Comment: You can filter out non-strings with remove-if-not: (defun my-concat( list )
  (format nil "~{~a~}" (remove-if-not #'stringp list)))

Answer (score 10):

To concatenate sequences to a string, use `concatenate 'string`.

```
(defun concat-strings (list)
  (apply #'concatenate 'string list))
```

To remove anything from the list that is not a string, use `remove-if-not`.

```
(defun concat-strings (list)
  (apply #'concatenate 'string
         (remove-if-not #'stringp list)))
```

If the argument is not a list, an error will be signaled by `remove-if-not`.  You can add the assertion before, of course, to give a more specific error message, but it does not really add value here.

```
(defun concat-strings (list)
  (assert (listp list)
          "This is not a list: ~s." list)
  (apply #'concatenate 'string
         (remove-if-not #'stringp list)))
```

*EDIT:*

As Rainer notes, `apply` only works on lists of limited length.  If you do not have reason to believe that your list cannot be longer than `call-arguments-limit` minus one, a `reduce` form is better:

```
(defun concat-strings (list)
  (reduce (lambda (a b)
            (concatenate 'string a b))
          (remove-if-not #'stringp list)))
```

Comment: Revisiting, it should be noted that if you want to concatenate a larger number of strings, it is more efficient to either work with streams (e.g., `with-output-to-string`), or to preallocate the result string and then fill it.

Answer (score 3):

[Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node143.html)

> concatenate result-type &rest
>   sequences

This one should work

```
(concatenate 'string result item)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Common Lisp Cookbook](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html#concat) :

```
(concatenate 'string "Karl" " " "Marx")
"Karl Marx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why limit yourself to lists?

```
(defun concatenate-strings (sequence)
  (reduce #'(lambda (current next)
              (if (stringp next)
                (concatenate 'string current next)
                current))
          sequence
          :initial-value ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents:

> (defmacro concatString (&rest strings)    `(concatenate 'string
>   ,@strings) )